# Get a value of element in ruby cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

i am making my first steps in writing cucumber features in Ruby On Rails application and am struggling with getting a value of an element.

The structure is something like this:

```
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
 <div data-value="test1" data-selectable="" class="option">TEST 1</div>
 <div data-value="test2" data-selectable="" class="option">TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the value of the div element when the data-value is "test1" ... so, TEST 1

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
within(:xpath, '//div[@class="selectize-dropdown-content"]') do
  find(:xpath, '//div[@data-value="' + value + '"]')
end
```

But it fails for not finding the "within" div.
So, I guess I am doing it wrong.

How does one go about it?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `text` method on the desired element

```
within('.selectize-dropdown-content') do
  find(:xpath, "//div[@data-value='#{value}']").native.text
end
```

Comment: I am getting an error already on the first selector:
Unable to find css ".selectize-dropdown-content" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

It is there, or at least should be, so i don't know why it can't be found.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it by adding `debugger` or `breakpoint` and checking elements exists in html or not? Is it related to ajax, js etc?

Comment: It seems like the element doesn't exists...actually. Yes, it is related to JS (selectize.js).

Comment: It is weird to me that when inspecting element (Chrome) i get everything, while "Show source" doesn't have this element. This is probably why it is failing.

Comment: :) so we can't find it like this... you need to enable `js`

Answer (score 0):

if there's a parent element for your block of code with ID you can do it like:

```
text = page.find('#parentID div:nth-child(1) div:first-child', visible: true).text
```

if you don't try it with javascript

```
text=page.evaluate_script('document.getElementsByClassName("selectize-dropdown-content")[0].getElementsByTagNam("div")[0].value')
```